# jquery-Slide Effect not consistent and happening too many times with jquery 1.7

Tags: jquery

I am using "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" , what I want is when I enter into some menu the dropdown should slide down smoothly but its not happening continuously.It is very inconsistent and sometime shows nothing and sometimes it continues to slideup and slidedown.
Please help me out of it.

I am using below code

Html :

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menuList">
      <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a>
        <div class="submenu">
          <div class="submenuInner">
            <div class="menus clearfix">
           <ul class="firstlist">
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Left 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Left 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Left 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Left 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Left 5</a></li>
           </ul>
           <ul>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Right 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Right 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Right 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Right 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu Right 5</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".menuList li").mouseenter( function() {
        $(this).find(".submenuInner").stop().css({"margin-top":"0"});
    $(this).children(".submenu").slideDown("slow");
    });

    //console.log("menuin");

    $(".menuList li").mouseleave( function() {
        $(this).children(".submenu").slideUp("slow");
        //$(this).find(".submenuInner").animate({marginTop:"-100%"},{queue :false,duration :50});
        $(this).find(".submenuInner").animate({marginTop:"-100%"},500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menuList li").mouseenter( function() {
        $(this).find(".submenuInner").stop(true, true).css({"margin-top":"0"});
        $(this).children(".submenu").stop(true, true).slideDown("slow");
    });

    //console.log("menuin");

    $(".menuList li").mouseleave( function() {
        $(this).children(".submenu").stop(true, true).slideUp("slow");
        //$(this).find(".submenuInner").animate({marginTop:"-100%"},{queue :false,duration :50});
        $(this).find(".submenuInner").stop(true, true).animate({marginTop:"-100%"},500);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CW62V/)

Comment: @NazirHussain if it solved your problem, you should accept the answer. ^^

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this code : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/9JVZ6/3/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menuList li").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find(".submenuInner").stop(true, true).css({
                "margin-top": "0"
            });
            $(this).children(".submenu").slideDown("slow");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).children(".submenu").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).find(".submenuInner").animate({
                marginTop: "-100%"
            }, 500);
        }
    );
});
```